# Launch application Java

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, launch

I made an application using bluetooth and so I had to use external libraries (bluecove). I am now looking to create a single executable to be able to give it to testers. I tested the executable JAR and it does not work, so I flip on a basic script.

I created a folder with all the java files inside and my external library and a folder with my pictures in it.

when I compile I have no error:

```
javac-cp bluecove-2.1.0.jar *. java
```

But in execution:

```
java -cp bluecove-2.1.0.jar Main
```

it gives me "error: Could not find or load main class Main"! I'm sur that my class contain my Main function Main.

What strange me is that in eclipse everything goes perfectly but not outside.

All those who have an idea and a hand to me is to thank in advance;)

Comment: I assume your Main class is in the bluecove jar file? Otherwise, it's simply not on the class path.

Comment: no my Main class is not in the bluecove jar file it's in a java file . Can you be more specific by "it's simply not on the class path" ?

Comment: Your -cp didn't add bluecove to the classpath, it set it as the ONLY thing on the classpath.  You need your compiled jar there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java -cp "bluecove-2.1.0.jar;." Main
```

linux:

```
java -cp "bluecove-2.1.0.jar:." Main
```

Note the `.` which indicates the current directory, it must be also on the classpath so that your class `Main` can be loaded.